# Unconstrained Optimization Introduction Question on Youtube

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm looking at this youtube introduction on unconstrained optimization for one variable [at this point in time](https://youtu.be/cu51Ea9BF9g?t=445) and it says that if:
f(x1) < f(x2) then we narrow the search range to [a, x2] instead of [a,b].

What if the top of the unimodal function f(x) lies between [x2,b].  Is that not still a possibility?  So f(x1) < f(x2), but we have not reached the top of the summit yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She is describing the setting where $\exists \alpha \in [a,b]$ such that $f$ is strictly decreasing on $[a,\alpha]$ and strictly increasing on $[\alpha, b]$ and we are interested in minimization.

Hence, if $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$, then $x^*$ is in $[a,x_2]$ since the other values that are bigger than $x_2$ has a higher function value.

Comment: Ah - It makes more sense - Thanks! I tatooed the unimodal concept graph (Earlier in the video) into my forehead and used it as my f(x) visual. Nice point balance BTW!